# Why is there SQL0445W warning while inserting casted string?

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to insert data into my table :

```sql
CREATE TABLE TABLE_TEST (
    DAT4 vargraphic(11 CODEUNITS16)
    )
ORGANIZE BY COLUMN 
IN TS21_IFKU01_32F@

INSERT INTO TABLE_TEST
SELECT cast((cast(222718 AS DECIMAL(31, 5))) AS VARGRAPHIC(11 CODEUNITS16)) AS dat4
FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

The INSERT return the following warning :

> SQL0445W  Value "222718.00000" has been truncated.  SQLSTATE=01004

I don't understand why, as I cast my value as vargraphic(11) before.
The return code is 2 instead of 0, and the batch considers the query to be failed.

Do you know why this warning appears ?

Comment: Because your string contains 12 characters, while you're trying to stuff it into an 11 character wide column.

Comment: When I execute only the select, the cast truncate the string to only 11 character, and the value returned is "222718.0000", so 11 character only

Comment: `db2 values cast((cast(222718 AS DECIMAL(31, 5))) AS VARGRAPHIC(11))` returns the same warning as well.

Comment: Ok, the warning comes really from the CAST, but Squirrel display this warning only when I do the INSERT. In command line, I also have the warning with the insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning is not from the insert, but from the cast as vargraphic(11).
With Squirrel, the warning is thrown only with the INSERT, not the SELECT, which lead me to believe it was the insert the cause of the problem.

This solution works :

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_TEST
SELECT left(cast((cast(222718 AS DECIMAL(31, 5))) AS VARGRAPHIC(40 CODEUNITS16)),11) AS dat4
FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```